# Refactor if-else with a logic of exists condition check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I have this two methods I want to refactor

```rb
def construct_discount_hash(product_adjustments)
  discounts = {
      events: {},
      subjects: {},
      products: {}
  }

  # product_adjustments is a model
  # This is a problem from legacy database structure where event_id, subject_id, product_id is in their own column
  product_adjustments.each do |adjustment|

    if (adjustment.event_id.present?)
      discounts[:events][adjustment.event_id] = {'$' => adjustment.amount, '%' => adjustment.percentage}
    end

    if (adjustment.subject_id.present?)
      discounts[:subjects][adjustment.subject_id] = {'$' => adjustment.amount, '%' => adjustment.percentage}
    end

    if (adjustment.product_id.present?)
        discounts[:products][adjustment.product_id] = {'$' => adjustment.amount, '%' => adjustment.percentage}
    end
  end

  discounts
end
```

and I will use above method results within below method

```rb
# discounts is a hash generated from above code, item is a rails model
def calculate_order_content_price(discounts, item)
    product = item.product

    if (item.product_variant.present?)
      price = item.product_variant.price
    else
      price = product.price
    end

    price_adjustments = {}
    popped_from = []

    if (discounts[:products][item.product_id])
      price_adjustments = discounts[:products][item.product_id]
      discounts[:products].delete(item.product_id)
      popped_from = [:products, item.product_id]
    elsif (discounts[:subjects][product.subject_id])
      price_adjustments = discounts[:subjects][product.subject_id]
      discounts[:subjects].delete(product.subject_id)
      popped_from = [:subjects, product.subject_id]
    elsif (discounts[:events][product.event_id])
      price_adjustments = discounts[:events][product.event_id]
      discounts[:events].delete(product.event_id)
      popped_from = [:events, product.event_id]
    end

    if (adjustment = price_adjustments['$'])
      adjusted_price = price + adjustment
    elsif (adjustment = price_adjustments['%'])
      adjusted_price = price + price * (adjustment / 100.0)
      discounts[popped_from[0]][popped_from[1]] = price_adjustments
    else
      adjusted_price = price
    end

    { price: adjusted_price, discount: (price - adjusted_price) }
end
```

I know from above code there's a lot of code-smell there. Firstly I'm thinking that the if-else logic can be refactored somehow. Can someone give an advice a technique that I can use to refactor that if-else condition? I'm confused because of the if-condition is checking for the existences of the value.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: _"This is a problem from legacy database structure"_ – wouldn't it make more sense to write a migration then in order to clean up the structure rather than working around it?

Comment: We try not to touch the database part, it will take a lot effort at this stage the company want to drive more features. So we take a decision, to basically try to refactor the rails part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to simplify a little bit your `construct_discount_hash` with two helpers:

```
def amount_and_percentage(adjustment, model)
  { adjustment.attributes["#{model}_id"] => { '$': adjustment.amount, '%': adjustment.percentage } }
end

def construct_discount_hash(product_adjustments)
  product_adjustments.each_with_object({}) do |adjustment, hash|
    case 
    when adjustment.event_id.present?
      hash[:event] = amount_and_percentage(adjustment, 'event')
    when adjustment.subject_id.present?
      hash[:subject] = amount_and_percentage(adjustment, 'subject')
    when adjustment.product_id.present?
      hash[:product] = amount_and_percentage(adjustment, 'product')  
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This one make it simpler. But initially, I wonder if it's possible to move it to a model so I can test it separately.

Comment: I'm not really sure, because it's a collection of objects. But anyways, you can easily test your helpers.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Not clean, but it should improve a bit from the legacy code, thanks man for the suggestion

Comment: I'll probably wait a bit more, if anyone has an idea for calculate_order_content_price method.

Comment: I can't figure what's `item` to make `item.product` work.

Comment: Oh, item is another object which contains product
`class OrderContent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :product_date, optional: true
  belongs_to :product_variant, optional: true
  has_one :order_ticket

  scope :not_removed, -> {where('removed IS NOT true')}
  ....
  ....
end`

Answer (score 1):

A refacto for you.

```
def construct_discount_hash(product_adjustments)
  # product_adjustments is a model
  # This is a problem from legacy database structure where event_id, subject_id, product_id is in their own column
  product_adjustments.each do |adjustment|
    adjustement_hash = {'$' => adjustment.amount, '%' => adjustment.percentage} if adjustement
    (discounts ||= {})[:events][adjustment.event_id] = adjustement_hash if adjustment.event_id.present?
    (discounts ||= {})[:subjects][adjustment.subject_id] = adjustement_hash if adjustment.subject_id.present?
    (discounts ||= {})[:products][adjustment.product_id] = adjustement_hash if adjustment.product_id.present?
  end
  discounts
end
```

I hope it will help you. Have fun.